# What is Jdbc type 5 driver

Tags: java, jdbc

What is a JDBC type 5 driver? What are the benefits of such a driver?

Can I get any links/tutorials about type 5 drivers?

Comment: Yeah I googled it, but I didn't get any examples for it.., That's what I am expecting from this forum...

Comment: The type 5 drivers use predictive technology to return the results just before the query is submitted.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989221/type-5-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 6):

There are currently four types of JDBC drivers.  See: [Types of JDBC technology drivers](http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/driverdesc.html)

There is [some speculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_5_.E2.80.93_The_Next_Step.3F) about what the next type would be like.

Comment: I've never seen that speculation before and it looks like typical market buzz without any technical merit. None of the differences mentioned in the article warrant a new type of driver. They are simply improvements for existing types.

Comment: @Joachim: The 1st and 3rd bullet points definitely seem like they would be implementation details that don't require a new type of driver at all.  I'm not sure about the 2nd and 4th without some clarification of what they mean.  The 5th one though, "Elimination of the need for proprietary extensions to the JDBC specification," seems like a new driver type would be in order.

Comment: it doesn't look like it would require another driver type. It would require some additional methods/interfaces for JDBC drivers to implement, but that would result in another JDBC release, but not in another driver type. Or put differently: those features could be implemented by drivers of any type, in my opinion.

Comment: @Joachim: Yeah, I see your point now and I agree.  It would make more sense for those to fall under a new version of the JDBC specification itself, not a new driver type.

Answer (score 6):

It is just  a thrid party implementation of JDBC. Type 5 is non-standard .

[image]

Comment: So a Progress type 5 driver is just a type 4 with extra marketing hype.

Answer (score 1):

It's a marketing hype. Progress e.g. shows it as:

- Type 1: JDBC-ODBC bridge
- Type 2: partial Java driver
- Type 3: pure Java driver for database middleware
- Type 4: pure Java driver for direct-to-database
- Type 5: highly-functional drivers with superior performance

They don't even state if Type 5 should be pure Java, and I believe it is some vendor bullshit because they don't want to say they have just a Type 2 driver.