# Type 5 JDBC Driver

Tags: java, jdbc

Is anybody has tried JDBC type 5 driver. Is it faster than JDBC 4 driver?

Comment: I thought this was just a hypothetical idea, rather than actual software?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not at all clear to me that "type 5" is really an official term, rather than just something invented by [DataDirect](http://datadirect.com). Every article about them that I can find seems to be written by or about DataDirect.

So, you could ask whether DataDirect's "type 5" driver is faster than the DataDirect type 4 driver for any particular database... but beyond that, the question doesn't currently make much sense.

Comment: I can hardly make out any actual features between the "faster, simpler" marketing gibberish on their website. Are they selling a JDBC driver that can connect to multiple RDBMS vendors?

Comment: Based on the description, you'd think Type 5 drivers should be able to bring world peace and solve the financial crisis as well...

Answer (score 3):

I thought types I through IV for JDBC drivers referred to the amount of native code used.  Type IV was always "100% pure Java".  What's Type V supposed to mean?  How much more pure can you be?

"...an album so black - it can't get much blacker..." - Spinal Tap

Comment: "This one goes to eleven - It's one louder"

Comment: 'Every time you try and operate these weird black controls that are labeled in black on a black background, a little black light lights up in black to let you know you've done it.'